# Testing @Effect when dispatch:false

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, ngrx

I am trying to test that an `@Effect({ dispatch: false })` is calling a `trackEvent()` method, but the effect does not raise any further action so it is not possible to subscribe to the effects observable as [described in the docs](https://github.com/ngrx/effects/blob/master/docs/testing.md).

My effect looks like this:

```
@Effect({ dispatch: false })
public trackPageView$: Observable<any> = this.action$
  .ofType(ActionTypes.TRACK_PAGE_VIEW)
  .map((action: TrackPageViewAction) => {
     this.angulartics2Service.trackPageView(action.payload.path);
  });
```

...and an extract of my spec looks like this:

```
it(`should call #trackPageView('${testPath}')`, () => {
  runner.queue(trackPageView(testPath));
  let s = TestBed.get(Angulartics2Service);
  expect(s.trackPageView.called).toBeTruthy(); // <-- fails!
});
```

My `angulartics2Service` looks like this:

```
let angulartics2Service: Stubbed<Angulartics2Service>;

angulartics2Service = {
  trackPageView: sinon.stub()
}
```

...where

```
export type Stubbed<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]?: T[key] & SinonStub;
};
```

How do I test this effect is calling `trackPageView()` method?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have the same exact problem

Answer (score 3):

Coming into this a little late, but I ran into this same problem and ended up here. Let's say I'm testing the following effects:

```
  @Effect()
  onPlaceOrder$ : Observable<any> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(CheckoutActionTypes.PlaceOrderAction),
    map(() => new PlaceOrderSuccess())
  );

  @Effect({ dispatch: false })
  onPlaceOrderSuccess$ : Observable<any> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(CheckoutActionTypes.PlaceOrderSuccessAction),
    tap(() => {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/checkout/thank-you');
    })
  );
```

This is how I ended up testing them:

```
  describe('when PlaceOrderAction is triggered', () => {

    let expected;
    const placeOrderAction = new PlaceOrder();

    beforeEach(() => {
      const placeOrderSuccessAction = new PlaceOrderSuccess();
      actions$ = hot('--a', { a: placeOrderAction });
      expected = cold('--b', { b: placeOrderSuccessAction });
    });

    it('should dispatch a PlaceOrderSuccess action', () => {
      expect(effects.onPlaceOrder$).toBeObservable(expected);
    });
  });

  describe('when PlaceOrderSuccessAction is triggered', () => {

    let expected;
    const placeOrderSuccessAction = new PlaceOrderSuccess();

    beforeEach(() => {
      actions$ = hot('--a', { a: placeOrderSuccessAction });
      expected = cold('--b', { b: placeOrderSuccessAction });
    });

    it('should call router.navigateByUrl', () => {
      //the actual effect doesn't trigger unless the following expect is run
      expect(effects.onPlaceOrderSuccess$).toBeObservable(expected);

      expect(router.navigateByUrl).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/checkout/thank-you');
    });
  });
```

I'm using jasmine marbles for testing by the way: https://github.com/synapse-wireless-labs/jasmine-marbles

I needed to trigger the `onPlaceOrderSuccess` effect by calling that first expect block (`expect(effects.onPlaceOrderSuccess$).toBeObservable(expected);`) in order to get the effect to run. Then it turned out that the returned value of a `dispatch: false` effect is actually the original action. So that's how you can test that your `trackPageView()` method is called.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is the only way i got it to run.
Unfortunately there is a lot of false information on testing `dispatch: false` effects out there.

Answer (score -1):

Subscribing to the observable should work but you still need to trigger with the appropriate action:

```
it(`should call #trackPageView('${testPath}')`, () => {
  runner.queue(trackPageView(testPath));
  let s = TestBed.get(Angulartics2Service);

  // set up whatever action is supposed to trigger the effect
  const sourceAction = new TrackPageViewAction();

  // set up the action observable to trigger the effect
  actions = hot('a', { a: sourceAction });

  // then subscribe to the effect
  effects.trackPageView$.subscribe(() => {
    expect(s.trackPageView.called).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

This assumes you've set up the effects/mock actions already which would look something like this:

```
let actions: Observable<any>;
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers)
  ],
  providers: [
    provideMockActions(() => actions),
    MyEffects  // whatever your effects class is
  ]
})
const effects: MyEffects = TestBed.get(MyEffects);
```